# Way to Prevent Stacking Pieces

Tags: movement, mouse, game-maker-dnd

I have a chessboard with all the black pieces that move with this code:
[image: Code1]]
I found that when I move the pieces, they will stack on top of each other. How can I prevent this?

I have since changed the code to this:
[image: Other Code]
When I move a piece over another it still picks that piece up, but now it will occasionally completely prevent any stacked pieces from moving. What can I do, and is there a way to do this while still being able to move one piece over top of another?

Also, the pieces origin and collision box ( all similar to the king) look like this: 
[image: spirte]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just use the function place_empty:**

```
if(place_empty((mouse_x div 32)*32,(mouse_y div 32)*32)){
    x=(mouse_x div 32)*32;
    y=(mouse_y div 32)*32;
}
```

In my case, my piece has dimensions 32x32 and its origin is at the top left.

To understand this calculation, I recommend looking at your own question ([Way to Round Numbers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/177566/way-to-round-numbers)), the answer of which helps to understand.

If you have difficulties in this, or in converting the code to DnD, just comment.

Comment: I have tried this and updated my question with the results. Can you take another look at it?

Comment: @K00lman How size is your piece? What is the origin of your piece?

Comment: The pieces are 64 by 64 and have the center at the corner, outside the collision box if that matters.

Comment: @K00lman What size grid have you chosen? (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/177566/way-to-round-numbers)

Comment: @K00lman If all pieces have their origin in the same location, I ask you to add an image to the question showing the origin location.

Comment: Added the image of the King piece with the origin and colliosion mask visible.

Comment: @K00lman Place the collision mask on the entire image (64x64). I suppose the size of each square is 64x64 correct? So use this: Expression - place_empty((mouse_x div 64)*64,(mouse_y div 64)*64)

Comment: How would I put that in DnD?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102051/discussion-between-k00lman-and-boneco-sinforoso).